# Dynamically assign height to a div

Tags: javascript, html, height

I want to do this: `<div class="container" style="height: calc(100vh - 349px);">` but dynamically through JavaScript because the "394" will vary.

I did this:

```js
<script>
        var afooter = document.getElementById('footer').positionInfo.height;
        var acontainer = document.getElementById('container').positionInfo.height;
        var dif = parseInt(acontainer) - parseInt(afooter);
        document.getElementById('contenedor').setAttribute('style','height: calc(100vh -' + dif + '');
</script>
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: looks like you forgot to add `px);` to your string there. `'height: calc(100vh - ' + dif + 'px);'`

Comment: Yes, your're right. But it doesnt work yet =(

Comment: What are you building? Is this for a sticky footer of sorts?

Comment: Yes, a sticky footer

Answer (score 0):

Try this function.

```
function resizeElementHeight(element) {
  var height = 0;
  var body = window.document.body;
  if (window.innerHeight) {
      height = window.innerHeight;
  } else if (body.parentElement.clientHeight) {
      height = body.parentElement.clientHeight;
  } else if (body && body.clientHeight) {
      height = body.clientHeight;
  }
  element.style.height = ((height - element.offsetTop) + "px");
}
```

Comment: would you like to share your repository?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround disabeling some things instead of not showing them, so the footer now has a fixed height. That way the `<div class="container" style="height: calc(100vh - 349px);">`is now working.

Thank you very much all for your help.